# Adding admin user accounts

Tags: users

I'm lost when it comes to adding a new admin user account. In the dashboard, I go to Settings -> Users, where I'm expecting to find a form where I could input a username, email address, password, etc.  Instead, I'm presented with a blank field layout. So I'm supposed to manually create fields for the username, email address, and password? What fields do I need to add and how do I know what to name the fields? Is there any documentation on this?

Neither the [users documentation page](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/users.html) nor the [user management](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/user-management.html) page offer any help. However, on the User Management page I read this sentence:

```
  To enable public registration, go to Settings → Users → Settings, and check the "Allow public registration?"
```

When I go to Settings -> Users -> Settings, all I see is a field to change the User Photo Location and a Save button, nothing else. I'm not trying to enable public registration, but the fact that that option is missing makes me wonder what else is missing.

I don't even know where to begin. Can someone point me in the right direction? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you visited the Plug-in Store to upgrade your installation to Craft Pro? User management is not a feature of Craft Solo. Craft Pro is free to test/develop with!

Comment: Ahhh, that explains it. Thank you!

Comment: Wanna add that as an official answer @AugustMiller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon setup, Craft is installed with a free *Solo* license. This means that the user generated as part of installation is “the only account you will be able to create.” (From the official [User Management](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/user-management.html) documentation)

In order to create more users, you’ll have to upgrade your installation to the *Pro* version through the control panel’s Plugin Store. *Pro* is free to test and develop with.